# cakephp AND condition

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have two tables

officetypes with fields:id[pk],name,under

officenames with fields:id[pk],name,officetype_id[fk]

two models
Officename.php

```
class Officename extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Officename';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Officetype' => array(
            'className'     => 'Officetype',
            'foreignkey'=>'id'
        )
    );
```

Officetype.php

```
var $hasMany = array(
        'Officename' => array(
            'className'     => 'Officename'               

        )
    );
```

Now how can i write conditions in controller to join theses two tables.My conditions is like this:

```
SELECT a. * , b. *  FROM officetypes AS a, officenames AS b    
    WHERE  
        a.id =3    
    AND 
        b.officeid = a.under
```

Comment: there's no officeid field in officenames table. Also you are not following correctly cakephp nameing convention: yoir tables should be office_types and office_names and the models: OfficeName OfficeType

Comment: Why are you writing SQL code in your controller? If you were to write SQL, why wouldn't you put in the model ( _fat model, skinny controller_)? However, why are you not using the **find** function? By defining the **hasmany** and  **belongsto** relations, you have already established the relation that cakephp should use.

Answer (score 0):

You just need do that:

```
$this->Officetype->find('all');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
$this->OfficeType->find('all')
```

you will retrieve the data you want.

Anyway in my experience is better to use Containable behavior, especially if you have in mind to expand your Models. With Containable you can retrieve only the models you want.
So do this:

```
class OfficeType extends AppModel {

public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $hasMany = array(
    'OfficeName
);
```

and then, in your controller use:

```
$this->OfficeType->find('all', array(
    'contain' => 'OfficeName',
    'conditions' => array('id' => 3)
     )
```